# Footer as a view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

On my footer I have a list of my categories. This means in every page view I loop over all my `Category` models. I also have a `Footer` model so I can choose the footer image, so I'm also calling that on every page aswell. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this..

Here's what I mean:

**views.py**

```
# These are included on every page..
def homepage_view(request):
    context = {
        "categories": Category.objects.all(), 
        "footer": Footer.objects.first(),
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name='main/index.html', context=context)
```

**models.py**

```
# Is there a better way to have a dynamic footer image?
class Footer(models.Model):
    footer_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="footer/")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Footer"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Footer"
```

Is it good practice to have a model just so I can have a changeable footer image? I don't need multiple footer models, I just want to be able to change my footers background image.

Comment: Why dont you do that in your template? Why would you want to hit your db with that?

Comment: @errorinpersona Which are you talking about? I'd love to minimize any db queries.

Comment: Your approach is pretty unusual. What exactly is your goal? Just display a random image in the footer or is the image actually tailored to the specific user?